# Debugging embbeded Linux application

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have an embedded Linux application running on an i.MX51 board. The way I update the kernel is to run an *update Kernel..* command during the boot process. There is plenty of output during the boot process that shows up in my serial port terminal.

During the boot process there is an error with my sound but if I search for the string in the kernel I can't find it. This makes me believe that the debugging output I am seeing during the boot process is not coming from the kernel.

So I am not sure if it is possible but what I would like to do is add a print statement in my kernel code that will show up on the serial port terminal to help me with debugging this driver. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: You might not be able to find exact string in kernel source code, it might be constructed dynamically using format specifiers such as `%s`, `%d` etc. The message might also come from your init or startup scripts, check what init system you use and what files are run.

Comment: Perhaps you might have done this already then you can ignore, set this  CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO?